# Can get Picasa feeds, can upload and download - can't delete

Tags: android, gdata, picasa

I'm using Yaniv Inbar's `GData` client to access Picasa albums from an Android app. I authenticate *via*

```
AccountManager.getAuthToken(account, "lh2", null, activity, null, null);
```

and can get user and album feeds, and download and upload pictures. What I **can't** do is `PicasaClient.executeDelete(Entry)` - it keeps giving me a 403 error, despite using the exact same authentication that the getFeed and upload/download ops use.

Do I need to set `client_id` and `client_secret` for delete but not get/put? If so, where?
[Authenticating to OAuth2 Services](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html) shows

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=" + your_api_key);
URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", your client id);
conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", your client secret);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
```

but I don't see `URLConnection` anywhere in the stack. I'm **guessing** that the hook will be somewhere in

```
authToken = authBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
ClientLogin.Response clientLogin = new ClientLogin.Response();
clientLogin.auth = authToken;
```

... but it's not exactly obvious where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. This was 100% iatrogenic.

I created the Entry with an "edit" Link like

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/%s/albumid/%s/photoid/%s
```

but set the `etag` to `null` because the etags I get in the album feed seem to be truncated somehow.

As soon as I replaced

```
photoEntry.etag = null;
```

with

```
photoEntry.etag = "*";
```

all was well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day!

Comment: *iatrogenic* meaning, caused by something you did during diagnostic procedures? That's a useful word!